# How to combinate LIKE + IN in SQL or JPA

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa

For example I have this strings:

```
Tesla is good car
Tesla is electric car
Opel is budget auto
```

And by words: **opel**, **tesla** I want to select all this strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SIMILAR TO` would work

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1 (
>   "id" INTEGER,
>   "mytext" VARCHAR(21)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tab1
>   ("id", "mytext")
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'Tesla is good car'),
>   ('2', 'Tesla is electric car'),
>   ('4', 'Opel is budget auto');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * from tab1 WHERE mytext SIMILAR TO '(Opel|Tesla|VW)%';
> ```

> ```
> id | mytext               
> -: | :--------------------
>  1 | Tesla is good car    
>  2 | Tesla is electric car
>  4 | Opel is budget auto
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ab0d8bbf66dc7a9d8a3f97143321e35b)*

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use this if your only two strings are 'Opel' and 'Tesla'?

Under the assumption that all your data looks the way you represented it in your post:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE your_field LIKE 'Tesla%' 
OR your_field LIKE 'Opel%'
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use an index effectively, query like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM tab
WHERE col LIKE ANY ('Tesla%', 'Opel%');
```